# N replaced by ! on ios Using itext pdf in java

Tags: java, ios, pdf, itext

**N** replaced by **!** on ios using `itext pdf` in java while sending it on android and desktops it works fine but when sending the pdf on ios n gets replaced.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Using this version of `itextpdf`.

Is it due to the older version..?

Cannot use `PdfReader` and `PdfStammper` because I am not editing existing pdf I am creating a new pdf.

Comment: can you attach the PDF file? Also, 5.5.6 is a version from 2015, so I'd definitely recommend moving to 5.5.13.3 (there shouldn't be a lot of API changes), or if you're starting a project from scratch, just go for iText 7.2.4 which is the newest version.

Comment: "while sending it": How do you "send" the PDF? It's possibly the source of the problem. Show your code and provide more information (incl. the problematic). At the moment, there isn't sufficient information to answer your question.